# How to read nested array

Tags: jquery

I have got this as response

```
[
    {
        "name": "Large, 100 Ml",
        "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
        "quantity": "1",
        "price": "75",
        "toppings": []
    },
    {
        "name": "Regular, 50 Ml",
        "image": "http://hostip:8080/OrderSnacks/JSON_images/icecream_cup_vanilla.jpg",
        "quantity": "2",
        "price": "150",
        "toppings": [
            {
                "name": "Regular, 50 Ml0",
                "value": [
                    "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Regular, 50 Ml1",
                "value": [
                    "Honey with Chocolate Sauce  10 ML",
                    "Honey with Carmel  10 ML"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can i read the toppings array values ??

I tried to read this way

```
for (var n = 0; n < toppins.values.length; n++) 
{
alert(toppins.values[n]);
}
```

But it is giving errror can't read property of undefined

could anybody please help me on this .

Comment: Is it `toppins` or `toppings`? Also, there are two layers above it.

Comment: `toppings` is an array.  It doesn't have a `value` property, its elements do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***Demo Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/WaAc6/)

*Javascript code:*

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i].toppings;
    for (var j = 0; j < obj.length; j++) {
        alert(obj[j].value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, it's `value` not `values` and `toppings` not `toppins` - per your JSON:

```
for (var n = 0; n < toppings.value.length; n++) 
{
alert(toppings.value[n]);
}
```